# Не отображается диалоговое окно скачивания файла

Tags: asp.net-core, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, asp, asp-net-core-mvc

У меня есть сервер asp net core откуда я хочу скачать PDF файл.
Так же подключен Swagger.

Когда я пытаюсь скачать файл через клиентское приложение, запрос выполняется, но ничего не происходит, а в логи выводится следующая информация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я захожу через Swagger, у меня появляется ссылка на скачивание файла, кликнув по которой файл скачивается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне бы хотелось чтобы файл автоматически скачивался.

Мой код контроллера:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult getPDF()
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {

        // Create a new MigraDoc document
        Document document = new Document();

        // Add a section to the document
        Section section = document.AddSection();

        // Add a paragraph to the section
        Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

        // Add some text and an image to the paragraph
        paragraph.AddFormattedText("Hello, World!", TextFormat.Italic);
        paragraph.AddImage("SomeImage.jpeg");

        var table = section.AddTable();
        table.TopPadding = Unit.FromMillimeter(1.2);
        table.BottomPadding = Unit.FromMillimeter(1.2);
        table.LeftPadding = Unit.FromMillimeter(1.2);
        table.RightPadding = Unit.FromMillimeter(1.2);

        table.Borders.Style = BorderStyle.None;
        table.Borders.Width = 0;

        table.Rows.LeftIndent = 0;

        Column column = table.AddColumn();

        column = table.AddColumn();

        column = table.AddColumn();

        column = table.AddColumn();

        column = table.AddColumn();

        column = table.AddColumn();

        column = table.AddColumn();

        column = table.AddColumn();


        var cell = row.Cells[0];
        cell.Shading.Color = Colors.Gray;

        cell = row.Cells[1];
        cell.Shading.Color = Colors.Blue;
        cell = row.Cells[2];
        cell.Shading.Color = Colors.Green;

        for (int i = 0; i < _status.Status.AutoMode.Reports.Count; i++)
        {
            var report = _status.Status.AutoMode.Reports[i];
            row = table.AddRow();
            row.Cells[0].AddParagraph(report.currentStep);
            row.Cells[1].AddParagraph(report.numObject);
            row.Cells[2].AddParagraph(report.command);
            row.Cells[3].AddParagraph(report.targetTime);
            row.Cells[4].AddParagraph(report.currentTime);
            row.Cells[5].AddParagraph(report.currentTemp);
            row.Cells[6].AddParagraph(report.currentPressure);
            row.Cells[7].AddParagraph(report.currentRadiation);

            switch (report.command)
            {
                case "Пропуск":
                    row.Shading.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
                    break;
                case "Пауза":
                    row.Shading.Color = Colors.LightYellow;
                    break;
                case "Возобновление":
                    row.Shading.Color = Colors.LightSeaGreen;
                    break;
                case "Принудительная остановка":
                    row.Shading.Color = Colors.LightCoral;
                    break;
            }

        }

        //Clean report List
        _status.SetEmptyReport();


        // Create a renderer for the MigraDoc document.
        PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);

        // Associate the MigraDoc document with a renderer
        pdfRenderer.Document = document;


        // Layout and render document to PDF
        pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

        // Save the document...
        pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream, false);

        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "HelloWorld.pdf");

    }
}
```

**UPD**

Вызов контроллера на клиенте

```
 const handleReport = async () => {
        await axios.get('/api/Report')
        .then(res =>{
            console.log('File download:',res);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log('File download error',err);
        })
        setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
    };
```

Comment: я так понимаю, что под клиентским приложением подразумевается не вьюха, а что-то другое

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Клиентское приложение - сайт. Я бы хотел чтобы при вызове контроллера,файл скачался из браузера.

Comment: ну вот создал я новый проект web api. добавил ваш код контроллера (установил пакет migradoc). создал index.html с гиперссылкой на метод контроллера. при клике на ссылку метод вызывается, pdf скачивается и открывается... вероятно, проблема в вашем клиентском приложении (скорей всего оно посложнее простой статической страницы). контроллер не причем.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов 
хмм действительно, таким образом у меня тоже сработало и это здорово, но почему это не работает через axios.get(...) ?  
Есть ли варианты провернуть это через axios? 
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: я тут поглядел в инете в чем может быть дело (сам не делал), предположение такое: требуется включить cors в приложении: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908949/asp-net-core-cors-webapi-no-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: @АлексейОбухов я объясню зачем мне это:
вызывая гет запрос, я бы хотел выполнять длительную операцию по завершении которой, скачался бы отчет с сервера ( return File(...) ). В данном слечае я могу конечно сделать какой нибудь флаг об окончании длительной операции, и после этого, беспалевно перейти по ссылке - чтобы скачать отчет, но мне кажется этот способ немного костыльным.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов CORS у меня как раз таки включен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, причина по которой файл не скачивался - безопасность.

Я нашел решение [тута.](https://coderoad.ru/41938718/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-axios)

Теперь мой клиентский код выглядит так:

```
const handleReport= async () => {
    await axios.get('/api/Report', { responseType: 'blob', })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('File download:', res);
            
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'report.pdf');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('File download error', err);
        })
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
};
```

Так же для решения этой проблемы [есть либа.](https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download)